# Regular expression How to bound colons to another statement without paretheses

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a regular expression that matches time in 1-12 hours:0-59 min:0-59 seconds+pm/am. The hour and pm/am are required, min and seconds are optional, but when min and sec appear, they have to be a two-digit num. Meanwhile, when calling .group() method, there should be 4 groups. For example, ("6","20",None,"pm"). My regular expression is

```
^([0-9]|1[0-2]):?([0-5][0-9])?:?([0-5][0-9])?(pm|am)$
```

But when I do :?, it will match the incorrect object 6::pm. How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Your groupings for the time part are optional, as well as the `:`

You can use a pattern to make the whole time part optional using a non capture group, and in the optional group, match the first one and make the second part optional to keep the order.

Put the am pm part outside of the non capture group so it is mandatory.

```
^([0-9]|1[0-2])(?::([0-5][0-9])(?::([0-5][0-9]))?)?([ap]m)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([0-9]|1[0-2])` Capture 0 - 12
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `:([0-5][0-9])` Match `:` and capture 00 -59
  - `(?::([0-5][0-9]))?` Optionally match `:` and capture 00 - 59
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `([ap]m)` Match am or pm
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jvQhTL/1) or a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zkHR1f).

```
import re

pattern = r"^([0-9]|1[0-2])(?::([0-5][0-9])(?::([0-5][0-9]))?)?([ap]m)$"
strings = [
    "12:59:59am",
    "12:59am",
    "12pm",
    "12am",
    "6::pm",
    "12",
]

for s in strings:
    print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
[('12', '59', '59', 'am')]
[('12', '59', '', 'am')]
[('12', '', '', 'pm')]
[('12', '', '', 'am')]
[]
[]
```